# Where should I train my Pokemon party?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I want to train my Pokémon to level 60 to defeat the Elite 4 in Pokémon Pearl.

This is my party:

- Lv. 54 Torterra
- Lv. 52 Palkia
- Lv. 44 Staraptor
- Lv. 45 Electabuzz
- Lv. 47 Rapidash
- Lv. 45 Tentacruel

I already started training Electabuzz on route 223. where is the best place to train my Pokémon?

Comment: This question is very localized/specific. It would be a better question if you made it more applicable to a general audience.

Comment: If i did that some answers may not be helpful to me, it is important that people know where i am at and what Pokemon i have.

Comment: If you ask for generally good places to train Pokémon, you can then pick the ones you like best or fit your team best. At the same time, the question will also help other people who might have a different team, but the same question.

Comment: @scenia there are no generally good places to train Pokemon it all depends on your Pokemon and level of yor Pokemon.

Comment: That's right. For example, I trained my Froslass (now lv. 65 in Platinum) mainly on route 222, whereas I trained my Blissey (now lv. 63 in the same game) in many other different places. I didn't train too much against wild Pokémon beacuse I had the Vs. Seeker and the trainers now have higher-leveled Pokémon ever since I beat Cyrus in the Distortion World.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that at that point in time, Route 222 is a better spot to train.

There is one fishermen named Alec on that road who has two Gyarados (the first Gyarados might be a Magikarp for the first few rematches) and you have two more trainers around nearby which means you can use the VS Seeker a few times and still get quite some rematches. Those should give you some EXP.

You also are on land (instead of being on the sea) where you can use your bike to charge up your VS Seeker faster than on Route 223.

If you manage to get a Lucky Egg (obtained from Chansey typically on Routes 209, 210 and in Trophy Garden), you'd be able to speed this up even further.

Once your Pokémon are in the vicinity of level 55, you should be able to take on the Elite 4 with some items to help; Hyper Potions, Revives are the basic ones you can use.

Unfortunately in Pearl, there are not as much trainers who can do rematches, when compared to Platinum.

Victory Road can be another good spot, if you don't feel like waiting for the VS Seeker (or don't want to rely on its randomness when trainers don't want to rematch). Having a Pokémon with Illuminate (e.g. Chinchou) at the first slot in your team, you can get plenty of wild Pokémon encounters there and in a few minutes, you should be ready to take on the Elite 4.

Comment: What is illuminate and what does it do?

Comment: @Oreo It's an ability that increases chances of wild pokemon encounters

Comment: I am having trouble levelling my Rapidash - it is no good training him at those three spots you mentioned because being a fire type, he is weak to water and rock.

Comment: @Oreo You can put the Exp Share on it and train your other Pokemon. It'll take just as much time to train two Pokemon one at a time.

Comment: @Oreo, since this is Pearl we are talking about, there are wild Purugly on route 222. They should give a nice amount of experience. Just run away from Floatzel, Wingull, Pelipper (5% chance to encounter), Gastrodon and Glameow. Don't worry, Purugly are not too rare there (15% encounter). There are also Chatot; that should help.